# I am not able to generate a table with movies that I have hardcoded into my code using a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to generate a table with the header movies, and display two movie names in the rows below. I want to do this hard coded as I am fairly new to mvc. I have a movie model, a controller called moviescontroller and a view as well as a partial view. When I go to open up the browser I receive the following error "CS0103: The name 'movie' does not exist in the current context
", which I assume means it doesn't recognize my context of Movies that I am trying to display.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class MovieListViewModel
    {
        //View Model 
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
@model WebApplication1.ViewModels.MovieListViewModel
@*
    View for Movies
*@
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movies</h2>

<table id="movies" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Movie</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@movie.Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@movie.Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Action result Index 
            var movies = new List<Movie>
            {
                new Movie {Name = "Fast Furious"},
                new Movie {Name = "Star Wars"}
            };
            var viewModel = new MovieListViewModel
            {
                Movies = movies,
                
            };
            return View(viewModel);

        }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {

        //Properties for Movie Model
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try `@Model.Movie.name`

Comment: Which line is giving you that error? Make sure you indicate that in your post. We can guess, but it's best to be explicit in your question.

Comment: Within the view, in the <td> tags. @Model.Movie.name doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is no variable in scope called `movie`, so when you try to access it using `@movie`, it fails because it doesn't exist. The way to access a model in a view is to access it via the view's `Model` property. Here's a simple example to loop over your movies:

```
@foreach (var movie in Model.Movies)
{
    <p>@movie.Name</p>
}
```

Notice that the `foreach` is accessing the list of movies by using `Model.Movies`. After that point, we now have a `movie` variable in scope that we can use to access the properties of each movie.

Therefore, your view becomes:

```
<table id="movies" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Movie</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var movie in Model.Movies)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@movie.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

which looks like this:

[image: movies table]

Comment: Thank you, I was not properly combining the for each logic into the html table

Comment: @Soccerplayer97 No problem, I'm glad it helped.